# How to check option is set to bash script?

Tags: shell-script

I'm creating a basic bash script which deploy a simple webapp. My current code is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "********************************************";
echo "Hello, I'm going to deploy the QuizProject";
echo "********************************************";

git pull --all;

#Only need to execute if option is present
composer install;

echo "********************************************";
echo "All the jobs done! Cheers";
echo "********************************************";
```

At the moment I'm running this script in the command as

```
bash deploy.sh
```

But this will execute all the commands in the bash file.

I want to make it if specific command is passed then only run the "composer install"

```
bash -composer deploy.sh
```

Comment: I don't want to validate any file name. Only needed to parameter set or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand your question that you want to control the function. Maybe it's best done with options. Here's one way:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_all=1
do_git=0
do_install=0
while getopts "gi" opt
do
    case $opt in
    (g) do_all=0 ; do_git=1 ;;
    (i) do_all=0 ; do_install=1 ;;
    (*) printf "Illegal option '-%s'\n" "$opt" && exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

clear

echo "********************************************";
echo "Hello, I'm going to deploy the QuizProject";
echo "********************************************";

(( do_all || do_git )) && git pull --all;

(( do_all || do_install )) && composer install;

echo "********************************************";
echo "All the jobs done! Cheers";
echo "********************************************";
```

If you call that script without options:

```
bash deploy.sh
```

both, git and install, will be called. If you call it with option `-i` (or resp. `-g`) only the install (resp. the git call) will be done:

```
bash deploy.sh -i
bash deploy.sh -g
```

You can also specify both options to do both, in one of these ways:

```
bash deploy.sh -gi
bash deploy.sh -g -i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "********************************************";
echo "Hello, I'm going to deploy the QuizProject";
echo "********************************************";

git pull --all;

#Only need to execute if option is present
if test "$1" = "-composer"; then
    composer install;
fi

echo "********************************************";
echo "All the jobs done! Cheers";
echo "********************************************";
```

Run the script as "bash deploy.sh -composer" to do the composer part.